# how to make a View tranparent to see background statusbar in Android

Tags: android

i have created an app which has a  TextView which contain some text.
i made it transparent by this code

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    android:id="@+id/Label"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                    android:text="Credit Balance 52$"
                    android:background = "#00000000"

/>
```

i want my application to be full screen but at the same time user will be able to see device statusbar behind TextView at top.

Please suggest me some solution of this problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using android.R.style.Theme_Translucent theme for your activity

Comment: i tried  this in my onCreate method                      setTheme(android.R.style.Theme_Translucent);                           but still it shows no statusbar.

Comment: use <activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent"> in manifest. see http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html

Comment: Thanks it worked for me.i created a new style.xml file and added it to my activity as you commented and thanks for the link.